# How to know if file is deleted and created in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I have a scenario where a script exists to remove files  according to the conditions.

Currently the script is like:
rem.sh

```
If [ -e file1 ]; then
    rm -f file1
elif [ -e file2 ]; then
     rm -f file2
 fi
```

I have another script which calls rem.sh

main.sh

```
1          rem.sh #should remove file1
2         touch file1
3          xxx
4          xxx
5         xxx
6         rem.sh #should remove file2 only
7         touch file2
```

If I run main.sh, It only remove file1 and create file1. Is there way to remove and create file2 and so on?

EDIT: I want to replace [-e file] with some condition which removes file2 when rem.sh is called for second time

Comment: Is the question "How to know if" or "how to remove"?

Comment: @Keldorn If i know “if a file is deleted and created”, I can olace that condition insted of “-e file”

Comment: rem.sh says "if file1 exists, remove file1, otherwise, if file2 exists, remove file2." Is that what it's *supposed* to do?

Comment: Sounds like you don't want `elif` and instead just have separate `if` blocks. Or even better, just `rm -f file1 file2` since this will delete the files only if they exists

Comment: I think maybe he only wants to delete one of the two files, if they both exist?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn yes.That is correct. I want to replace that condition (-e file) and place a condition which allows to remove file2 when rem.sh is called for second time

Comment: Why bother with rem.sh at all? Why not just replace your first call to rem.sh with `rm -f file1` and the second one with `rm -f file2`?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn I can do that. But I’m looking to create a seperate script to remove files

Comment: Why? What's the purpose of the separate script?

Comment: @chepner To remove those files, we have to call with sudo. If I create a seperate file, I can just call the script with sudo

Comment: your `if/elseif` designed to do either one branch or possibly the other.  If you want both change into two `if` statements.

Comment: @karakfa If I do that, each time I run rem.sh - file1 will be deleted

Comment: Please clarify your question. People are ready to help but do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: I also don't understand. Can you write comments in `main.sh` saying for example `rem.sh  # Should only remove file1` or `rem.sh # Should remove file1 and file2`

Comment: So you want to run the same script, in the same conditions (ie `file1` and `file2` exist) but have the `rem.sh` script behave differently the second time?

Comment: @Keldorn yes please

Comment: As is, `rem.sh` can not know if it is the second time it is running, if all things are the same. You could have some history saved somewhere, in another file. But chances are you can just simplify the problem as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

instead of complicating, what I think you just want to delete the contents of the files at certain points of your main script.  So instead of `rm/touch` pair, just dump null into the file.

```
1   >file1
2   xxx
3   xxx
4   >file2
5   xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have the condition work for each file? So you don't have to type the file name each time? If so, you can just have a counter or use the read command to send user input to a variable, then use that in your if statement.